# Python Deciphering

Tags: python

I am trying to decipher the standard "a = 1, b = 2, c = 3..." cipher in Python, but I'm a bit stuck. My message that I want decrypting is "he" -- " 8 5 ", but because of the ordering of my if statements, the output is "eh". Does anybody know how to solve this?

```
import re
import sys
message = " 8 5 ";
map(int, re.findall(r'\d+', message))
if "++" in message:
    sys.stdout.write(" ")
if "--" in message:
    print()
if " 1 " in message:
    sys.stdout.write("a")
if " 2 " in message:
    sys.stdout.write("b")
if " 3 " in message:
    sys.stdout.write("c")
if " 4 " in message:
    sys.stdout.write("d")
if " 5 " in message:
    sys.stdout.write("e")
if " 6 " in message:
    sys.stdout.write("f")
if " 7 " in message:
    sys.stdout.write("g")
if " 8 " in message:
    sys.stdout.write("h")
if " 9 " in message:
    sys.stdout.write("i")
if " 10 " in message:
    sys.stdout.write("j")
if " 11 " in message:
    sys.stdout.write("k")
if " 12 " in message:
    sys.stdout.write("l")
if " 13 " in message:
    sys.stdout.write("m")
if " 14 " in message:
    sys.stdout.write("n")
if " 15 " in message:
    sys.stdout.write("o")
if " 16 " in message:
    sys.stdout.write("p")
if " 17 " in message:
    sys.stdout.write("q")
if " 18 " in message:
    sys.stdout.write("r")
if " 19 " in message:
    sys.stdout.write("s")
if " 20 " in message:
    sys.stdout.write("t")
if " 21 " in message:
    sys.stdout.write("u")
if " 22 " in message:
    sys.stdout.write("v")
if " 23 " in message:
    sys.stdout.write("w")
if " 24 " in message:
    sys.stdout.write("x")
if " 25 " in message:
    sys.stdout.write("y")
if " 26 " in message:
    sys.stdout.write("z")
```

Comment: you should organize the codes in a dictionary, like: `codes = {' 21 ': 'u', ' 25 ':'y'}` and so on... then you do `sys.stdout.write( codes[input] )`

Comment: You should look into using the `ord()` function

Comment: what @SaulloCastro said, except I would programatically generate that dictionary `import string`  `codes = {}`  `for item in string.ascii_lowercase: codes[string.ascii_lowercase.find(item)+1] = item `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution does not work because you do not look at each number in the input string from its beginning, but for any occurence of it.

Suppose your input is `8 5 8`, your output would still be `eh`.

Instead of using the `in` operator, you should have a loop among all numbers of the message:

```
for code in map(int, re.findall("\d+", message)):
    if code == 1:
        sys.stdout.write("a")
    -- ... and so on until 26
```

You should also use the tipsgiven by others, that consist in using a code dictionary to avoid all those `if`statements.

Answer (score 6):

This becomes a lot easier if you use a mapping rather than a series of `if` statements:

```
>>> import string
>>> d = {str(x):y for x,y in enumerate(string.ascii_lowercase,1)}
>>> d['++'] = ' '
>>> d['--'] = '\n'
>>> message = ' 8 5 '
>>> ''.join(d[x] for x in message.split())
'he'
```

Here, I use all strings as keys to the dictionary since you want to support `'++'` and `'--'`.

Answer (score 2):

Since it looks like you are more interested in why your approach isn't working that getting a concise solution I'll try to avoid more complicated methods of approaching this problem (ASCII mappings/dictionaries and give you a few pointers on how you could approach this.

Firstly, you have a message that is a String. You want to look at each letter of this string and find the correct letter it encodes, so you will want to parse the string and look at it one letter at a time, from left to right.

You can use a `for` loop to grab a letter, and then do your comparison on that single letter. Do this one letter at a time and write the output at each stage.

Once you get this working you can look at optimising your code, but it is important to understand the basics first.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing what you're doing now, you'll want to

- Split the `message` string into each component (`8` and `5` (or `11` for that matter, etc))
- Iterate through each component in order...
- ... And "decipher" its value into a letter.

(That `map(int`... line does nothing, by the way.)